# Returning back to UK

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens

I was asked by the Home office to leave the UK after exhausting all my appeal, so in 2016 I returned to India voluntary at my expense.

I would like to know how I can return back to the UK and what are the options and visa categories to apply for from India.

Comment: You haven't given any details of your history, but based on what you have written the Home Office will regard you as being at very high risk of overstaying. Your chances of getting a visitor visa are effectively nil. You might try applying for a work visa, but you'd need a really good case before it's considered seriously.